# How to implement OpenSSL's SSL_Write() by using PHP

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

I am trying to connect to a server using PHP script. The server is set by SSLv3, I think maybe I need use `SSL_Write()` to process the message which will send to the server. But I do not find the related function in PHP. So, I wonder which function should I use.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use curl to do this?

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, for one, because it might not be an HTTPS connection…

Comment: @duskwuff outstanding. It will be even more so if Maggie answers the question rather than us guessing.

Comment: @duskwuff，@WhozCraig sorry for late reply, the server cannot process curl.

Comment: If your statements about the server and `SSLv3` are accurate then my guess is, you should be using TLSv1 and above. Most servers and user agents/clients refuse to do SSLv3 nowadays. TLSv1 is on the hit list but is is still available in some places. To future proof your app use TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the TLS stream transport. There is no direct equivalent to the `SSL_Write()` function; PHP does not implement a functional interface to SSL.

Here is a simple example of using the TLS transport to make a connection to an HTTPS web server. This is not an ideal application of the transport, as PHP already natively supports an HTTPS file wrapper; I'm simply using it here as an example of interacting with a publicly accessible TLS server.

```
$fh = stream_socket_client("tls://example.com:443", $errno, $errstr);
if ($fh === false) {
    die("Failed to connect: error=$errno $errstr");
}
fwrite($fh, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"\ );
while (!feof($fh)) {
    print fgets($fh);
}
```

If you need to set specific options on the TLS connection, you can do so by creating a stream context (using `stream_context_create()`) before making the connection. Refer to the PHP documentation for more details.

Comment: @ duskwuff  I try this code, but nothing show in the screen, so I think maybe there are some problem else.